# Admin console is blank

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am trying to run the admin console but I click on the admin button a blank browser opens without anything in it. What am I missing? I have looked at the FAQs and the forum but still could not solve the issue. I have the server.properties file and I have added the sqlserver.jar to the lib

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='mysgwt'>
<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.tools.SmartGwtTools" />
<inherits name="com.smartgwtpower.SmartGwtPower" />
<inherits name="com.smartgwtpower.tools.Tools" />

<!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
<entry-point class='org.kai.client.MySGWT' />

<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
<source path='client' />
<source path='shared' />
```

Code:

```
public class MySGWT implements EntryPoint {

private HLayout hLayout;

public void onModuleLoad() {

    if (!GWT.isScript()) {
        KeyIdentifier debugKey = new KeyIdentifier();
        debugKey.setCtrlKey(true);
        debugKey.setKeyName("D");
        Page.registerKey(debugKey, new KeyCallback() {
            public void execute(String keyName) {
                SC.showConsole();
            }
        });
    }

    GWT.log("init OnLoadModule()...", null);

    hLayout = new HLayout();

    IButton adminButton = new IButton("Admin Console");
    adminButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            com.smartgwtpower.tools.client.SCPOWER.openDataSourceConsole  ();

        }
    });

    IButton visualButton = new IButton("Visual Console");
    visualButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            com.smartgwtpower.tools.client.SCPOWER.openVisualBuilder();
        }
    });

    hLayout.setMembersMargin(20);
    hLayout.addMember(adminButton);
    hLayout.addMember(visualButton);

    hLayout.draw();
}
}
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="MySGWT.css">

<title>MySGWT Project</title>

<script> var isomorphicDir = "mySGWT/sc/"; </script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="mysgwt/mysgwt.nocache.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

<!-- RECOMMENDED if your web app will not function without JavaScript enabled -->
<noscript>
  <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red;  background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
    Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
    in order for this application to display correctly.
  </div>
</noscript>


 </body>
</html>`
```

This is the eclipse logging

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[WARN] Aliased resource:         file:/C:/myworkspace/mySGWT/war/mySGWT/sc/skins/Enterprise/images/button/button_Over_stretch.png==fil    e:/C:/myworkspace/mySGWT/war/mysgwt/sc/skins/Enterprise/images/button/button_Over_stretch.png
[WARN] Aliased resource:                         file:/C:/myworkspace/mySGWT/war/mySGWT/sc/skins/Enterprise/images/button/button_Over_stretch.png==fil    e:/C:/myworkspace/mySGWT/war/mysgwt/sc/skins/Enterprise/images/button/button_Over_stretch.png
[WARN] 404 - GET /mySGWT/sc/skins/Enterprise/images/button/button_Over_stretch.png (127.0.0.1)    1450 bytes
```

Comment: how can i debug it. it is standard code of SmartGWT

Comment: Make sure your browser isn't blocking the pop up. I also usually initiate the admin console through its javascript hooks, i.e in the browser's javascript console I write isc.showConsole(). This loads the admin console.